# How to publish an Angular 2 application into Azure web app?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I published my Angular 2 application into Azure web app by following [this link](http://abusanad.net/2016/07/24/publish-angular-2-app-from-visual-studio-to-azure/). After that when I browse web app URL I am facing so many issues in **zone.js** file and also when I refresh my web app URL I got different errors.

Please see the below image for more information about my issues.

[image]

But my application is working in my local machine with out any issues. this is the code I wrote in index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Todo List Angular2 Sample</title>

<link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Secure Hash Algorithm -->
@*<script src="js/jsSHA-master/src/sha.js"></script>*@
<script>
      window.config = {
          apiBaseUrl: '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toDoListAPIURL"]'
      };

</script>

<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I resolve those issues?

Comment: It looks like the server is to blame here. I visited the page and you get different results each time. You need to look to see if the server is limiting the number of requests it responds too or something of that nature.

Comment: Still also I am facing same issues once again when I was published my angular app into azure web app.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Please update your question with the new error you are facing.

Comment: I resolved my errors, please see the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Teddy Sterne, when I removed/comment the below lines of code from **web.config**. and published web app into azure it's working fine without any errors.

```
 <!--<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="NotFound">        
    --><!--<denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="2"/>--><!--      
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="20" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="60000" />
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>-->
```

I think the problem with the above lines of code, because the code allows 20 requests per minute.